# SQLXML on Azure Web sites

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, sqlxml

My application is using the library SqlXML and I am trying to publish this application to Azure Web Services.

Once I publish it I get this error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {83D0FC3E-8B31-4B35-A1B2-346BA3954514} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I checked stacktracing and its on a method that uses the SqlXML.

I checked if the dll is referenced as an assembly in web.config and it is

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.Data.SqlXml, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
```

I checked whether the DLL is present and its there.

Is there a way to install SQLXML on Azure Web Services?

Comment: If you're trying to install a COM object, then no - you cannot do such an install on Azure Web Apps.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172009.aspx) to access SQL Server via Microsoft SQLXML Managed Class, I could reproduce this issue after deploying my web application to Azure Web App. I also tried to register this library by using [Regsvr32](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx) on [KUDU > Debug console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console), but fail with the following error:

[image]

> Is there a way to install SQLXML on Azure Web Services?

As David Makogon stated that you could not install SQLXML on Azure Web Apps. As I known, Azure Web Apps run in a sandboxed environment, so there are some limitations, for more details, you could refer to [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). Per my understanding, you could leverage Cloud Services or Azure Virtual Machines which could provide your with more controls on your Web Server. You could follow this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm) for a comparison between Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, and Cloud Services.